# How to make values entered in the text field appear in the sentence?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing an assignment where I have to make up 10 random sentences and I have to create text fields. These text fields are supposed to include whatever I put in them inside the sentences. I need help with the code that will include the words inside the sentence?

My html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Assignment 4</title>
<h1> Assignment 4 - Sample Solution </h1>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  Name:         <input type="text" id = "input" size="10" />
  <br />

  Verb Phrase:  <input type="text" id = "input2" size="10" />
  <br />

  Adjective:    <input type="text" id = "input3" size="10" />
  <br />

  Noun:         <input type="text" id = "input4" size="10" />
  <br />
HOW MANY SENTENCES? <select id = "numOfSentences" size = "1">

    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>

<button id = "displaySilly">
    Display Silly
</button>
<p id = "output"></p>
<script src = "silly.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my javascript is

```
var names = ["Alice","Rowena","Carol","David","Erin"];
var verbs = ["jumped on", "ran from", "scolded", "yelled at","talked to"];
var adjs  = ["yellow","big","smelly","hairy","bad"];
var nouns = ["bear","tree","rock","student","instructor"];

// variables for the sentence components
var name, verb, adj, noun; 

// display silly sentences 
document.getElementById('displaySilly').onclick = function() {
    // get number of sentences from drop down
    var numOfSentences = 
        document.getElementById('numOfSentences').value;
    //convert to integer
    numOfSentences = parseInt(numOfSentences);
    // initialize results string
    var results = "";
    // create required number of silly sentences 
    for (var i = 1 ; i <= numOfSentences ; i++) {
        //pick components at random from arrays 
        name =
            names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
        verb =
            verbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * verbs.length)];
        adj =
            adjs[Math.floor(Math.random()  * adjs.length)];
        noun =
            nouns[Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length)];
    // concatenate to form a sentence
    // add to other sentences 
    results = results + name + " " + verb +
              " the " + adj  + " " + noun +
              ".<br />";
}

// display the silly sentences 
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = results;
} //*** END onclick handler
```

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you have a good start.  So what's not working?

Comment: everything working I just don't know how to make the words entered in the text field get displayed in the sentences

Comment: It is still not clear to me what it is you want *exactly*. Do you want the words from your inputs to be added to your random sentences at random? Can't you just add them to the correct array of 'default' words before you start generating the sentences then?

Comment: Yes I want the words from my inputs to be put into the first sentence of my random sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
names.push(document.getElementById('input').value)
```

this will push the value from the name into the array.  you will need to do this for each array and input.

you will need to do this before the randomizer section of your code.

Comment: names.push(document.getElementById('input').value);
verbs.push(document.getElementById('input2').value);
adjs.push(document.getElementById('input3').value);
nouns.push(document.getElementById('input4').value);